# How can I get matrices for practicing Jordan normal form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I would like to practice the algorithm for the transformation from a matrix to its jordan normal form (with change of basis).

To do so, I wrote this script that generates random $n \times n$ matrices, with $n \in \{2,3,4,5\}$

```
import random, numpy

n = random.randint(2,5)

matrix = []

for i in xrange(n):
    line = []
    for j in xrange(n):
        line.append(random.randint(-10, 10))
    matrix.append(line)

A = numpy.matrix(matrix)

print("Here is your %i x %i Matrix" % (n, n))
print(A)
```

This way of generating random matrices isn't very good for the following reasons:

- The numbers can get really ugly ([example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B2,5,1%7D,%7B1,10,7%7D,%7B1,-2,3%7D%7D))
- Sometimes it is not possible to calculate the decomposition of the matrix ([example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B-1,-9,2,7,-7%7D,%7B-6,-9,3,2,-1%7D,%7B3,2,-8,-1,4%7D,%7B-3,0,4,-5,-6%7D,%7B7,-3,-1,-7,-2%7D%7D))

Do you know either pages with many examples of "good" matrices up to $5 \times 5$ or do you know how to change my script?

Comment: I don't know how you'd do it in numpy, but one approach would be to build up a matrix with known Jordan block structure and then perform a similarity transformation with an orthogonal or unimodular matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could generate a Jordan normal form $J$ randomly, then an invertible matrix $X$ randomly and have the algorithm compute $Y=XJX^{-1}$ for you. $Y$ would be your exercise.

Comment: This has the added advantage that you know the right answer - it generates problems and an answer sheet.  The disadvantage is that $Y$ might not be an integer matrix, even if $X$ and $J$ are.

Comment: If you manage to ensure $X$ is integral and its inverse is integral, then your $Y$ will be integral as well.

Comment: Sure, but generating such an $X$ randomly seems non-trivial.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'm not sure how one is supposed to respond to such speculation, but I'll just say the comment was a statement of fact directed at the OP, and not a comment direct at your comment, as you seem to have interpreted it. I'll direct a counterspeculation at your comment though and say that generating an invertible unimodular matrix sounds like something that would be really well-documented online.

Comment: He is looking for a practical way to hack together some examples, not advanced algorithmic way of selecting unimodular matrices.  (It might suffice to take $X$ to be a random upper-triangular matrix with $1$s along the diagonal to give him a diverse enough example set, for example.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If it's not speculation you can write "is" instead of "seems", then. As for practicality, if there is a python code out there that generates such matrices, there is nothing more practical than cut-and-paste.

Comment: Thanks for your answer rschwieb. I've created this script: https://gist.github.com/3283952